# Print out a pointers variables that points to a value in a sequence

Tags: c, pointers

I am stuck in this exercise in which I am not able to correctly print the value of "maxcount" and "mostnum" on the screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define size 100
void analyzeFrequencies(int sequence[], int* mostnum, int *maxcount, int 
length)
{
    int i=0, j=0, count=0;
    for(i=0;i < length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i; j < length; j++)
        {
          if(sequence[i]==sequence[j])
          {
            count++;
          }
        }
        if(count>=*maxcount)
        {
           maxcount=&count;
           mostnum=&sequence[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, length;
    int *mostnum, *maxcount;
    int sequence[size]={};
    char answer;

    do
    {
        length=0;
        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter numbers between 0-1000: ");
            scanf("%d",&sequence[i]);
            if(sequence[i]<0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(sequence[i]>1000)
            {
                printf("Wrong input, try again.\n");
            }
            length++;
        }
        analyzeFrequencies(sequence, mostnum, maxcount, length);
        printf("The number %d occurs the most time, in total %d times\n", *mostnum, *maxcount);
        printf("Do you want to enter another sequence (yes = y, no= n)? ");
        scanf("%c",&answer);
    }while(answer == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

What I have to do in this exercise is to print on the screen which number in the sequence occurs most time and how many times. My problem appears when I have to do this with pointers, because I am not sure what I am getting and do not have any sense.
Here you can see the rules.

---

> You​ ​should​ ​write​ ​a​ ​function​ ​​`analyzeFrequencies()​​` ​that​ ​computes​ ​which​ ​of​ ​the integers​ ​that​ ​have​ ​occurred​ ​the​ ​most​ ​times​ ​in​ ​the​ ​sequence​ ​and​ ​how​ ​many​ ​times​ ​it​ ​has occurred.​ ​Since​ ​the​ ​function​ ​computes​ ​two​ ​different​ ​results,​ ​the​ ​function​ ​should​ ​take these​ ​results​ ​as​ ​pointer​ ​variables​ ​as​ ​arguments.
>
> Rules​ ​for​ ​​`analyzeFrequencies()​`:
>
> - It​ ​should​ ​not​ ​return​ ​a​ ​value​ ​(the​ ​results​ ​are​ ​computed​ ​via​ ​pointers).
> - The​ ​function​ ​must​ ​take​ ​the​ ​​sequence​ ​entered​ ​by​ ​the​ ​user​​ ​as​ ​an​ ​array​ ​argument
> - The​ ​two​ ​computed​ ​values​ ​(number​ ​that​ ​occurs​ ​the​ ​most​ ​and​ ​number​ ​of occurrences)​ ​should​ ​be​ ​taken​ ​as​ ​pointer​ ​variable​ ​arguments.
> - The​ ​function​ ​may​ ​not​ ​take​ ​any​ ​further​ ​input​ ​from​ ​the​ ​user​ ​and​ ​may​ ​not​ ​print anything​ ​on​ ​the​ ​screen.
>
> Other​ ​rules:
>
> - The​ ​sequence​ ​must​ ​be​ ​entered​ ​in​ `​​main()​​` ​and​ ​all​ ​printouts​ ​should​ ​also​ ​be​ ​from `main()`​.
> - After​ ​the​ ​sequence​ ​have​ ​been​ ​analysed,​ ​the​ ​user​ ​should​ ​be​ ​asked​ ​if​ ​he​ ​or​ ​she​ ​wants to​ ​enter​ ​a​ ​new​ ​sequence.

Comment: In C, arguments to function are passed *by value* which means the values are copied. Modifying a copy doesn't modify the original. Do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C* to understand what the pointer-arguments are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the *reason* the pointers are used in this situation. Since C lets you return only one item from a function, the exercise uses pointers to set values inside the function instead.

What this means is that you are not supposed to declare pointers in the `main`. Instead you should declare `int`s, and pass the result of applying address-of `&` operator to them:

```
int mostnum, maxcount;
analyzeFrequencies(sequence, &mostnum, &maxcount, length);
```

Inside `analyzeFrequencies` you keep pointers, and assign like this:

```
if(count>=*maxcount)
{
   *maxcount = count;
   *mostnum = sequence[i];
}
```

Now the values you assign inside the function are performed on local variables that you declared in `main`, because you passed them by pointer.

Since you read `*maxcount` inside `analyzeFrequencies` before assigning it, you must add an assignment before entering the loop, like this:

```
int i=0, j=0, count=0;
*maxcount = 0; // <<== Add this line
for(i=0;i < length;i++)
```

**Note:** You have other mistakes in the code unrelated to passing pointers. For example, when you print "Wrong input, try again" you should adjust `i` to refer to the same position again, otherwise the wrong output would remain in the sequence.